# Simplest way to get correct string from ResultSet, or empty string if null

Tags: java, android, jdbc

I have some ResultSet from SELECT MySQL query. The value is string, but it can be null. What is the simplest and shortest way to get correct string from ResultSet, or empty string if null?

```
String.valueOf(rs.getObject("column"));
```

short way, but may be, not correct and fast

```
output = rs.getString("column");
if(output == null){output= "";}
```

right way, but long, with additional variable, and not comfortable especially when I have to create parceble value from ResultSet - something like:

```
Discount.create(rs.getString("Code"), rs.getString("Df"), rs.getString("Di"));
```

Are there any other ideas? (I understand that I can make my parceble values nullable)

Comment: Why don't you use `COALESCE` in the query instead?

Comment: I understand MySQL way too, but the question is about java way.

Comment: It’s not beautiful, but if you prefer: `Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString("column")).orElse("")`.

Comment: Better than using `Optional` is `Objects.requireNonNullElse(rs.getString("column"), "")` was this what you were after?

Comment: you can create a function that accepts resultset and index and return string or "", like: getStringFromResultSet(rs, index)

Answer (score 3):

If the only downside of the last solution that you proposed is complex syntax, why not create a function like this?

```
private String getStringOrNull(String columnName) {
    String output = rs.getString("column");
    return output == null ? "" : output;
}
```

Or if you don't want extract the separate function, you can use `Optional` instead:

```
String output = Optional.ofNullable(rs.getString("column")).orElse("");
```

Comment: Optional is a nice option, I like it